# Error: "Cannot find module" when using npx create-remix@latest

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, create-react-app, typescript-module-resolution

Good day,
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run npx create-remix@latest. I'm receiving the following error message:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:553
      throw e;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\5164864a48bff686\node_modules\path-scurry\dist\cjs\index.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:547:14)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:621:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1034:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\5164864a48bff686\node_modules\glob\dist\cjs\glob.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\5164864a48bff686\\node_modules\\path-scurry\\package.json'
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I updated Node.js to a stable version (20.9.0).
2. I cleared the npm cache using npm cache clean -f.
3. I attempted to install create-remix manually using npm install -g create-remix.
4. I verified that my Node.js installation directory is correctly added to my system's PATH.
   Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the same error. I suspect it might be related to a problem with module resolution. How can I resolve this issue and run npx create-remix@latest successfully?
   This is really worrisome, Please

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the you have the latest npm version:
https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm